# Is there any Python 3 module to create PDF files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation

I have for some time looking for something to be able to create PDFs and integrate with my current project in Python 3. The usual references are [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/) or [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/). But these two are not yet compatible with Python 3. I do see that since 2010 there has been some [discussion](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2010-February/009269.html) about the port in Reportlab, but as of today I can't find any reference to the port.

Another alternative is to use an intermediate format from Python 3 to be consumed in another program, wrapped with a subprocess call. [Relatorio](http://relatorio.openhex.org/) does this. I might consider doing something similar or even generate XHTML/CSS and use [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/).

Comment: Reportlab is being ported now: https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/branch/py33

Comment: Reportlab 3 (released [February 2013](http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/relnotes/30/)) now supports Python 3.3+

Comment: Actually both Reportlab and its "nicer" interface django-easy-pdf now work on Python 3 (now that xhtml2pdf has beta Python 3 support) – I explained how to get things to work [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43097663/544059).

Comment: for people still looking for an alternative to Reportlab and fpdf, check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme). It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) library with the [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) (not py2cairo, that's for python 2) binding works with python 3.x and can produce PDF output (among others).

Comment: Following your suggestion I start looking for some library around cairo/pango and I found this https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pypdflib which it has some nice abstractions of documents. It doesn't officially support python3, but based on the support for python3 on cairo and pango it seems feasible with a few modifications.

Comment: Yeah, cairo itself is good for drawing but only passable for creating text. Pypdflib sounds good. An alternative might be to use pango (http://www.pango.org/) with cairo for text. If you install pygtk, it has a pangocairo module. But except from some examples, there isn't much documentation.

Comment: Just to inform to the future adventures in python 3 and pdf's I end up porting a python2 library to python 3 https://bitbucket.org/cyraxjoe/py3fpdf.

Comment: @cyraxjoe Your bitbucket link is 404-ing.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, is now hosted on github https://github.com/cyraxjoe/pypfop

Answer (score 5):

There is a new kid on the block which look promising. 
It supports print css features like page break.

Try [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/)

Comment: OP is talking about specifically using a PDF processor within Python 3, not a stand-alone service. Edit: never mind I see that weasyprint is on github and can be scripted. Here is a more relevant link: https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint

Answer (score 3):

In the end I find it difficult to work with pycario/pango, pycairo stil misses some method for png's and PIL is not quite yet supported in python3, also carries a lot of dependencies (the idea of using pycario) <strike>so I end up porting a python 2 library to python 3, is not very advanced but gets the jobs done for some basic pdfs, it's called [py3fpdf](https://bitbucket.org/cyraxjoe/py3fpdf)</strike>

--- *update* --

It turn out that p3fpdf didn't get the jobs done n_n'. So to tell the end of the story, I made a *preprocessor* to [apache fop](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) it s called [pypfop](https://bitbucket.org/cyraxjoe/pypfop). I just recently decouple with the full project, It  a work in progress specially with documentation, the examples may be illustrative.

Answer (score 2):

You could got the HTML/CSS route and use [prince](http://princexml.com/) although it's not free software.

If your source is not too complex, you can also try a pure python solution as in http://code.activestate.com/recipes/189858-python-text-to-pdf-converter/

Answer (score 0):

You could shell out and call [text2pdf](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/)

Comment: The question already suggests using xhtml2pdf as an alternative, so 'do the same with text2pdf' doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Port for 2.7 and 3.3 is currently a work in progress:

https://github.com/nakagami/reportlab

PIL has not yet been ported to Python3, so ReportLab will not work completely.

Answer (score 0):

Pillow is a pretty good port of PIL to Python 3, and it's now available in Debian experimental and Ubuntu 13.04.  That should unblock a Python 3 port of ReportLab, which I would love to see.  @nakagami: your github report seems to fail for me with `python3 setup.py build` but it could be shallow.  How official is your port?  Have you contacted the RL folks to see if they're interested in your work?  I don't think their code is available in a public vcs.