# How to convert a html document into a pdf using report lab with python

Tags: python, html, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to convert a html document that I have created into a pdf using report lab. The html document is below. I am unsure on how to do this and I have looked online and cant seem to find a solution for this.

html document

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Convert to Pdf</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h2>Convert to pdf</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at tempus massa. Quisque congue dui venenatis rutrum imperdiet. Nulla congue magna sit amet magna posuere, in elementum felis dapibus. Mauris maximus feugiat lorem, a bibendum orci fringilla a. Pellentesque rhoncus dignissim tempus. Aliquam semper convallis odio ut pharetra. Nunc bibendum neque at bibendum ornare. Curabitur lobortis odio ac turpis tincidunt, at venenatis nibh blandit. Integer id arcu maximus, blandit urna ut, tempor odio. Pellentesque tempus, mi a finibus pellentesque, ex magna lacinia elit, a semper nibh orci non nulla. Nunc felis metus, congue a odio vitae, porttitor pellentesque sem. Fusce vehicula tincidunt dolor at dictum. Integer cursus, risus quis finibus dapibus, nulla dolor dapibus massa, et luctus enim dui a nunc. Sed facilisis sapien at risus commodo, eget sollicitudin ex eleifend. Proin ipsum ipsum, condimentum in mauris vel, rutrum aliquam magna.

Aenean ac odio ante. Proin eget urna est. Fusce at dui dignissim, tincidunt magna eget, dictum nisl. Donec enim ipsum, feugiat a tristique vitae, suscipit non risus. Pellentesque libero leo, pellentesque ut neque ut, pharetra volutpat ex. Pellentesque purus neque, varius eu dolor eu, placerat ullamcorper velit. Etiam volutpat blandit tortor non pellentesque. Donec ac risus lacus. Pellentesque sagittis vitae odio quis vulputate. Praesent efficitur urna mollis, cursus tellus euismod, pulvinar sem. Morbi maximus orci nisi. Fusce tempor condimentum lacus nec pulvinar. Aenean tristique eu nibh vitae facilisis.

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would love to hear about strictly ReportLab solution, most probably with a conversion routine.

Comment: @fatih_dur: I'm not sure if this is possible using strictly Reportlab. They do have an example of [converting HTML to RML](https://www.reportlab.com/dev/docs/tutorial/), but RML is part of the commercial package. From the [docs](https://www.reportlab.com/dev/docs/pagecatcher/): "The free ReportLab core API lets you create PDF files directly using the Python scripting language; our commercial RML2PDF Report Markup Language product lets you specify printed documents in easy-to-understand XML and converts these to PDF."

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31543123, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1377446

Answer (score 8):

As you already know how to use ReportLab, I guess that this would do the job : 
https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf

**xhtml2pdf**

A library for converting HTML into PDFs using ReportLab

Sample code, taken from the Github :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright 2010 Dirk Holtwick, holtwick.it
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

__version__ = "$Revision: 194 $"
__author__  = "$Author: holtwick $"
__date__    = "$Date: 2008-04-18 18:59:53 +0200 (Fr, 18 Apr 2008) $"

import os
import sys
import cgi
import cStringIO
import logging

import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa

# Shortcut for dumping all logs to the screen
pisa.showLogging()

def dumpErrors(pdf, showLog=True):
    #if showLog and pdf.log:
    #    for mode, line, msg, code in pdf.log:
    #        print "%s in line %d: %s" % (mode, line, msg)
    #if pdf.warn:
    #    print "*** %d WARNINGS OCCURED" % pdf.warn
    if pdf.err:
        print "*** %d ERRORS OCCURED" % pdf.err

def testSimple(
    data="""Hello <b>World</b><br/><img src="img/test.jpg"/>""",
    dest="test.pdf"):

"""
Simple test showing how to create a PDF file from
PML Source String. Also shows errors and tries to start
the resulting PDF
"""

    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        cStringIO.StringIO(data),
        file(dest, "wb")
        )

    if pdf.err:
        dumpErrors(pdf)
    else:
        pisa.startViewer(dest)

def testCGI(data="Hello <b>World</b>"):

    """
    This one shows, how to get the resulting PDF as a
    file object and then send it to STDOUT
    """

    result = cStringIO.StringIO()

    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        cStringIO.StringIO(data),
        result
        )

    if pdf.err:
        print "Content-Type: text/plain"
        print
        dumpErrors(pdf)
    else:
        print "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
        print
        sys.stdout.write(result.getvalue())

def testBackgroundAndImage(
    src="test-background.html",
    dest="test-background.pdf"):

    """
    Simple test showing how to create a PDF file from
    PML Source String. Also shows errors and tries to start
    the resulting PDF
    """

    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        file(src, "r"),
        file(dest, "wb"),
        log_warn = 1,
        log_err = 1,
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src)
        )

    dumpErrors(pdf)
    if not pdf.err:
        pisa.startViewer(dest)

def testURL(
    url="http://www.htmltopdf.org",
    dest="test-website.pdf"):

    """
    Loading from an URL. We open a file like object for the URL by
    using 'urllib'. If there have to be loaded more data from the web,
    the pisaLinkLoader helper is passed as 'link_callback'. The
    pisaLinkLoader creates temporary files for everything it loads, because
    the Reportlab Toolkit needs real filenames for images and stuff. Then
    we also pass the url as 'path' for relative path calculations.
    """
    import urllib

    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        urllib.urlopen(url),
        file(dest, "wb"),
        log_warn = 1,
        log_err = 1,
        path = url,
        link_callback = pisa.pisaLinkLoader(url).getFileName
        )

    dumpErrors(pdf)
    if not pdf.err:
        pisa.startViewer(dest)

if __name__=="__main__":

    testSimple()
    # testCGI()
    #testBackgroundAndImage()
    #testURL()
```

Or you can use **pdfkit** :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

Before using it you need to install some things :

```
pip install pdfkit
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Sample code to generate pdf :

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://stackoverflow.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out2.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Thanks for reading!', 'out3.pdf')
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16784445)

Comment: Hello,
I edited my comments, based on what you said.
Sorry if I'm making some mistakes, I'm kinda new here.
Could you read my awnser again and give me other advices ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you use django framework you could use django-easy-pdf. I think it's the least painfull way to generate PDF from Html. Here's the template and views of my project:

```
#Import the easy_pdf rendering
from easy_pdf.rendering import render_to_pdf_response

#Here's the detail view function
def detail_to_pdf(request,id):
    template = 'renderdetail.html'
    kucing = Kucing.objects.get(id = id)
    context = {'kucing' : kucing}
    return render_to_pdf_response(request,template,context)
```

The Template is:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_style %}
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
            color: #333333;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        <div class="main">
            <h1>PROFILE : {{ kucing.nama }}- ID:{{ kucing.id }}</h1>
            <img src="/media/{{ kucing.foto }}"><br>
            <p>Nama : {{ kucing.nama }}</p><br>
            <p>Hp : {{ kucing.hp}}</p><br>
            <p>Poin : {{ kucing.poin }}</p><br>
            <a href="{% url 'kucing_makan' kucing.id %}">Makan</a>
            <a href="{% url 'kucing_berburu' kucing.id %}">Berburu</a>
            <hr>
            <h5><a href="{% url 'kucing_home' %}">Back To Home</a></h5>|
            <h5><a href="{% url 'kucing_list' %}">See Another Kucing</a></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

You also able to use Class Based Views by overriding PDFTemplateViews. You can see more on the [Docs](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0-dev1/).

Comment: I was surfing on github and found something related to pdf. there's a module named txt2pdf you can see it [here](https://github.com/baruchel/txt2pdf)

Comment: If you want full web project of my answer. Please, contact me I'll send it to you.

Comment: Caveat: django-easy-pdf 0.1.1 does not support Django 3.0+ because it removes `django.util.six`.