# Convert html to pdf with material icons in python using pdfkit

Tags: python, pdfkit

I need to render a page to PDF file which includes Material icons but it doesn't seem to work.

**templates/pdf.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    * {
      font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  Just test 
  <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
</body>
</html>
```

**gen.py**

```
import pdfkit
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

html = render_to_string('pdf.html')
pdfkit.from_string(html, 'out.pdf')
# I tried this version but it doesn't work either
# pdfkit.from_string(html, 'out.pdf', css=['https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'])
```

`out.pdf` only contains the text `Just test`. Are there any chance to fix it?

I've just also created the issue in pdfkit repo - [issue](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/96)

Comment: What does `html` look like?  i mean like print(html)

Comment: If you are using django.. try `django-easy-pdf`.. Have a look here(2nd answer)... let me know if it doesnt work and i will have a look but i think it will help you in this instance  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233906/how-to-convert-a-html-document-into-a-pdf-using-report-lab-with-python

Comment: It also encountered the same problem. I just figure out the way to get it works. Will add the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues to solve and I got it done in an acceptable manner.

1. Css.

   - Only `inline styles` work. External styles don't work.
   - Wkhtmltopdf supports `-webkit-` prefix, so that some css properties need to add the prefix to work properly.
   - download external css files if required. Use `<style>{% include 'style.css' %}</style>` in django template to seperate out the css files.
2. Icon fonts and custom fonts do not work.

   - download required svg icons instead of using icon fonts.

   > a. use `{% include 'icon.svg' %}` to include the font icons
   >
   > b. only `path`, `fill` element in svg xml are supported
   >
   > c. you can change the color and height of svg in the svg xml content.
   >
   > d. download svgs at [Material Icon](https://material.io/icons/)
   >
   > e. you can use pngs instead but it is not easy to change the icon color and size.

   - use system font or install the font manually inside the serving instance.