# How to convert boostrap template to pdf in django

Tags: jquery, django, email, pdf, pdf-generation

I have invoices bootstrap template in which data come with ajax response after invoice filled with response data then i want to convert that exact template with its css into pdf, so i can send it through email using django server. Is there is anyway to convert template with its data and css into pdf. I tried so many things but can't get desire result.
[image]

I want exact pdf of this invoice with css. Thanks in adnvance.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, you might want to use [WeasyPrint (Vanilla)](https://weasyprint.org/). I use the Vanilla / Original Version because it's straightforward and easy to use.

Excerpt from my code in the [repository](https://github.com/CodexLink/Django_SSPA_CRUD/blob/master/CrudSimulation/views.py#L164) that uses it. But I will also some demonstration anyway.

1. Create an HTML View from where you want to render the content.

```html
# inside pdfRenderer.html

{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Simple Task Management | Summer Skilling #1</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% include "databoard.html" with pdfRenderMode=True %}
</body>
<!-- ! Content Ends Here -->

</html>
```

Note: `databoard.html` contains the **layouts** that I wanna render inside my PDF. Look at here [instead](https://github.com/CodexLink/Django_SSPA_CRUD/blob/master/CrudSimulation/template_context/databoard.html). While pdfRender.html is the body where I wanna load `databoard.html` inside.

2. Use it like Normal Django Views but instead, we use WeasyPrint's functionalities to render it as a file.

```py
# Inside views.py

from weasyprint import CSS, HTML
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

template_pdfRenderer = "pdfRenderer.html" # Refer to the html file I want to render at my PDF at.

# Create a Filename of the PDF.
pdfFileName = "%s_%s.pdf" % (
    self.request.user.username,
    datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S%m%d%Y"),
)

# Renders The HTML with Model's Content.
ml_string = render_to_string(
    template_pdfRenderer,
    {"DataSets": UserTasks.objects.filter(Task_Owner=self.request.user.uuid)},
)

# Let WeasyPrint Get HTML String of ml_string.
# Input the location from where it would be saved (in server's part / perspective)
# Add some stylesheets incorporated with the HTMLs. DO NOT INCLUDE CSS INSIDE THESE TEMPLATES AS THEY WON'T WORK.
html = HTML(string=html_string).write_pdf(
    target="userdata/ExportedPDFs/%s" % (pdfFileName),
    stylesheets=[
        CSS("CrudSimulation\static\css\material.min.css"),
        CSS("CrudSimulation\static\css\sc_require-min.css"),
    ],
)

# Instantiate FileStorage.
fs = FileSystemStorage("")

# Open The Saved PDF and Let User Saved It By Packaging it to the HttpResponse.
with fs.open("userdata/ExportedPDFs/" + pdfFileName) as pdf:
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type="application/pdf")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="%s.pdf"' % (pdfFileName)
    return response

# Once we're done, returning to a particular URL.
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("data_user_view"))
```

**Result**

[image]

[Output of the File.](https://github.com/CodexLink/Django_SSPA_CRUD/blob/master/ExampleExportPDF/CodexLink_13181504182020.pdf)

Note: The rendering feels like it was saved via `Print as PDF` but the flexibility of adding content is a nice addition as to why I recommended this.

For a basic setup, you might want to look at this guide > [Using Python WeasyPrint generate HTML to PDF in django](https://micropyramid.com/blog/generate-pdf-files-from-html-in-django-using-weasyprint/) but, I primarily used this [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/08/how-to-export-to-pdf.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I installed weasyprint but terminal give this error 
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
Then i installed GTK and set path but this error still appear i can't project

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I haven't seen that issue though. My OS is Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I personally would use reportlab

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/

Try the instructions here.

There is also a good answer here using another package:
[Generate PDF from HTML using Django and Reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543123/generate-pdf-from-html-using-django-and-reportlab)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i already use both of things but i don't get desire result